# How to remove retweet using twitter4j

Tags: java, android, twitter4j

Twitter4j 2.x had a method called getRetweetedByMe which could be used to delete a retweet. However, I am using twitter4j 3.0 and that method has been removed. I tried another solution but I am getting a error saying I can't removes someone else status. How can I accomplish removing retweets with this version of twitter4j.

My Approach:

```
        List<Status> retweets = twitter.getRetweets(statusId);
        for (Status retweet : retweets)
            if (retweet.getRetweetedStatus().getId() == statusId)
                twitter.destroyStatus(retweet.getRetweetedStatus().getId());
```

Comment: I don't understand why you got downvoted - this is a perfectly valid question (I'm facing exactly same problem). Just a thought - aren't you "destroying" original tweet by using `retweet.getRetweetedStatus().getId()`, shouldn't it be `retweet.getId()` in `twitter.destroyStatus`?

Comment: Yea, that actually solved by problem.

Answer (score 4):

I found out easier way (and probably a way which creators of the API wanted us to use). Part of my "unretweet" method:

`long myRetweetId = status.getId();
if (status.getUser().getId() != getCurrentUser().getId()) {
  // not my retweet, but the original tweet
  myRetweetId = status.getCurrentUserRetweetId(); // <-
}
twitter.destroyStatus(myRetweetId);`

Working with `Twitter4J 4.0.1`.